# Why Char.MinVal / .MaxVal are not static?

Tags: .net, char

```
public struct Char
{
 public const char MaxValue = (char)0xffff;
 public const char MinValue = '\0';
}
```

Why don't make this fields to be static? What for it's always allocating additional memory for each char while this two values are permanent?

**Edit**: I don't know how I could forget about been static implicitly!

Comment: +1 tou counter the -1 this is a legit question i guess, dunno why you got downvoted

Comment: I can understand the downvote to some extent. It currently includes incorrect *statements* rather than asking, "Doesn't this mean that [...]." Not sure it's worth either up or down myself though.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because they are static.

Const fields are static implicitly.

Answer (score 13):

const fields are implicity static. From section 10.4 of the spec:

> Even though constants are considered
>   static members, a *constant-declaration*
>   neither requires nor allows a *static*
>   modifier. It is an error for the same
>   modifier to appear multiple times in a
>   constant declaration.